# Can I make my own Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I often find myself asking questions that I realize the answer to a day later.

I want to know if there is a Stack Exchange template that I can host myself on localhost so that I can put up questions, answer them myself, and if I can't, write them on an appropriate Stack Exchange online.

I know I can use forums, or make my own copy of Stack Exchange manually, but I like Stack Exchange format more, and wanted to know if I have to start from scratch or if it's already available somewhere.

Comment: Oddly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296990/what-are-the-various-se-site-bounce-rates-where-researching-and-phrasing-a-ques